# values from views not getting rendered in HTML page using Django in pycharm IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

I have copied a project on which I was working on using normal editor to Pycharm IDE so that I can debug further while developing the site. But when I run the project in pycharm, values are not getting rendered in HTML file but was when using editor.

In pycharm, I have created venv and installed all the libraries. As a result, website also opens when

> python manage.py runserver

is ran. But the values which I submit in the form, the values are not getting rendered somehow in html page.

HTML snippet is given below.

```
    <div class="order-1 text-center sticky-top chartbutton border-bottom shadow-sm">
        <form action="{% url 'trend' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ new_prodform }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="var-class">
        var prod_name, end_date;
        prod_name = '{{prod_name}}'; <!-- prod_name value is null here after submit -->
        end_date = '{{end_date}}';   <!-- end_date value is null here after submit -->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'trend/chart_plot.js' %}"></script>
```

Views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    filled_form = ProductForm(request.POST)
    if filled_form.is_valid():
        product = filled_form.cleaned_data['product']
        new_prodform = ProductForm()
        prod_milestone = main_query_script(product) #some function to retrieve and return trend details in dict form

        context_dict.update(prod_milestone)
        context_dict.update({'new_prodform':new_prodform})
        return render(request, 'trend/chart.html', context=context_dict)
else:
    form = ProductForm()
    context_dict.update({'new_prodform':form})
    return render(request, 'trend/chart.html', context=context_dict)
```

Please let me know if more info I should add. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean with 'the values are not getting rendered somehow in html page.'?

Comment: When I submit the data in the form via html page, data is received in "product" variable but that is not available in "chart.html" after passing it via context.

Comment: are you sure that prod_name and end_date are correctly added in the context_dict? I suppose they are in prod_milestone variable, did you try to debug it?

Comment: whenever I try to debug, the values are not getting rendered. I am replacing all the source files which I took backup before. Then after migrations, in pycharm, sometimes it renders and other times it doesn't. It's so weird behaviour I am observing. And when it doesn't render, I have to clear browser cache again and again.